# Проблема с двумя переменными в while

Tags: python, python-3.x, while, логические-выражения

Есть код, суть которого заключается в разбиении уравнения(строки) на переменные(-abc+3a+4ac+2ac = [-abc, 3a, 4ac, 2ac]). Столкнулся со сложностью в функции while. При 2 переменных она работает не корректно(должна завершаться при -1 у обоих переменных, но завершается как хочет, было и при 0,4). В интернете только примеры с одной переменной, мб она и не может 2 переменных содержать, поэтому решил спросить: Может ли и что не так?

```
def simplify(p):
    e = []
    q = p.find('-')
    w = p.find('+')
    while w and q  != -1:
        if q < w:
            if q == -1 or q == 0:
                e.append(p[:w])
                p = p[w+1:]
                q = p.find('-')
                w = p.find('+')
            else:
                e.append(p[:q])
                p = p[q:]
                q = p.find('-')
                w = p.find('+')
        else:
            if w == -1:
                if q == 0:
                    break
                e.append(p[:q])
                p = p[q:]
                q = p.find('-')
                w = p.find('+')
            else:
                e.append(p[:w])
                p = p[w+1:]
                q = p.find('-')
                w = p.find('+')
    e.append(p)
    return e

print(simplify("-abc+3a+4ac+2ac "))
```

Также есть еще вопрос: можно ли в if/elif/else делать ссылки на другой  if. Например действия при "if q == -1 or q == 0" и действия при последнем в цикле else одинаковы:

```
e.append(p[:w])
p = p[w+1:]
q = p.find('-')
w = p.find('+')
```

Сгруппировать их я логически не могу. Def возвращает результат, т.е не подходит. Классы слишком сложно ради копирования строк делать(хотя хз, классы не понимаю пока). Смысла в этом мало, проще копировать-вставить, просто любопытен какой-нить легкий метод реализации, если он есть.

Comment: Да, это условие

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так должно быть:

```
while (w != -1) and (q != -1):
```

А то, что в коде - совсем другое.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы получить из `"-abc+3a+4ac+2ac "` - `['-abc', '3a', '4ac', '2ac ']` достаточно манипуляций:

```
t = "-abc+3a+4ac+2ac "
tt = t.replace("-", "+-")
ttt = [x for x in tt.split("+") if bool(x)]
print ttt
# ['-abc', '3a', '4ac', '2ac ']
```

Ваш вопрос касательно ссылки на if. Условия первичны, код под ними вторичен. Т.о. в вашем варианте, чтобы не дублировать код, блок под if можно поместить в функцию.

```
def f(x, y):
    <блок кода>

if <условие>:
    if <условие>:
        f(1, 1)
    else:
        f(1, 0)
else:
    if <условие>:
        f(0, 1)
    else:
        f(0, 0)
```

Ну или придумывать логику как избавить от определённых условий, включив их в другие, сделать дерево ветвления одномерным - без вложенности и пр.